# GoかJavascriptでローカルタイムをUTCに変換する時にサマータイムなどを考慮させるには

Tags: javascript, go

Webアプリケーションを作成中で、web側をJavascript、DB側をGoを使って書いています。
Web側で時間を選択して、それをGoに送るのですが、web側で選ぶ時はローカルタイムなので、仮に日本ならばその時は2019-08-22T18:28:44+09:00となります。これをDB側に送る際に自動的にString型に変換され（送る時は必ずString型になる）、Goでtime.Parseを使い、時間型に変換しなおしています。

```
t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", "2019-08-22T18:28:44+09:00")
//2019-08-22 18:28:44 +0900 JST

fmt.Println(t.UTC())
//2019-08-22 09:28:44 +0000 UTC
```

この書き方で一応ローカルタイムをUTC時間に変更できるようですが、この時にサマータイムなどは考慮されて変換されるのでしょうか？１時間の差なので、そこまで気にはしませんが、もしサマータイムなども考慮して変換する方法があれば教えてください。
UTCへの変換はGoで行なっていますが、JavaScript側でも大丈夫です。UTCに変換したものをString型で送れば良いので。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 夏時間を考慮する必要があるのは、2019-08-22T18:28:44+09:00という文字列を作る前の段階です。"+09:00"などのオフセットを決めるときに夏時間を考慮する必要があります。この文字列はどうやって作っていますか?

Comment: JavaScriptでnew Date()としています。その際に時間をnew Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)などで指定したりしています。new Date()とするとローカル時間の現在の日付と時間を取ってくれます。（これはPCの環境設定などで別の時間帯を選択するとそれに応じた時間をとってくれる）

Comment: すみません。自分でコメントに回答して気づきましたが、どうやらJavaScriptでnew Date()とやるとサマータイムも考慮した上でのローカル時間を取ってくれるようです。PCの環境設定をカナダにしてみたらきちんとサマータイムの時間とUTC時間との誤差を取得してくれました。int32_tさん、回答として書いてくれれば解決済みにさせていただきます。

Comment: Dateの挙動はそのとおりなのですけども、やはり「Dateオブジェクトをどうやって文字列化しているか」は書いていただかないと答えにくいですね。

Comment: 開発環境でSenchaのExt.jsを使っておりまして、その中にあるExt.Date.formatを使って指定したフォーマットでString型に変換していますが、やっていることはDate型をtoString()で文字列化しています。new Date().toString()と書けば
"2019-08-26T13:50:02+09:00"という文字列を取れます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2019-08-22T18:28:44+09:00` という文字列にはタイムゾーンオフセットの情報が入っていますが、タイムゾーンそのもの(JSTやKSTなど)の情報が欠落しています。タイムゾーンの情報がないため夏時間を考慮することはできず、「タイムゾーンオフセットをローカル時間から引けばUTCの時刻になる」という計算だけが可能です。タイムゾーンオフセットを得るときに夏時間を考慮する必要があります。

[`Ext.Date.format()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.Date.html) では `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` が使われているようです。

`getTiemzoneOffset()` は、その`Date`オブジェクトが表すローカル日時に従ったオフセット値を返すようECMA Scriptの仕様で決められています。夏時間にも対応しています。よって、`Date`オブジェクトにローカルの日付を設定したあとに`getTimezoneOffset()`を呼べば夏時間対応はできていることになります。